# Creating a Wordpress Plugin - Form Submission Fails when passed value of 00x00

Tags: forms, wordpress

I am writing a pretty simple plugin.  I notice that when I submit a form with a text field with a value that is 2 or more digits followed by an x then followed by two or more digits that the form doesn't submit it redirects me to the index page.  I get an apache error log message : [error] [client ::1] script '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php' not found or unable to stat but that is all of the info I can find.

To narrow down the problem, I made a super basic form that runs in the admin section with only one field. When it is submitted it calls a javascript alert to show the $_POST value.  This works all day long UNTIL I enter 00x00 or any digits really with an x between them, 123x123, 999999999x999999999 etc...

In it's intended use this field would have a dimension like 120x120 but for what ever reason the x is causing something weird to happen.  Any ideas?

Here is the stripped down basic example, added to an admin menu page

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'alert("' . $_POST['image_url'] . '");',     '</script>';   
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>">
<input name="image_url" id="image_url" type="text" maxlength="200" value="00x00"/>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: check mod_security, make sure it exclude that rule with post of digit with x in the middle

Comment: It wasn't mod_security but it was a Wordpress plugin called Wordpress Firewall 2.  You pointed me in the right direction and I was able to add appropriate IP's to the Wordpress Firewall 2 whitelist.  Problem solved!  Thank you so much for taking the time to check out my post, you saved me a lot of time!